# jquery div switch

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've recently been working on a website where everything was working just fine on localhost but when I moved it to a server the change div function started loading weird and I have no idea why. The bug is more visible when you cycle through portfolio button and contact button.

The website is optimized only for Firefox 9.

http://raduvulcu.comuf.com/ro

This is the script that loads the pages:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    var href = $('.pagination a').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
            $('#content').load(toLoad)
        }                                           
    });

            $('.pagination a').live('click',function() {

                var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
                $('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
                $('#load').remove();
                $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load"></span>');
                $('#load').fadeIn('slow');
                window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
                    function loadContent() {
                        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
                    }
                    function showNewContent() {
                        $('#content').show('slow',hideLoader());
                        $(window).scrollTop('');
                    }
                    function hideLoader() {
                        $('#load').delay(300).fadeOut('slow');
                    }

                return false;
        });         
});
```

Comment: You have not asked a question. You just stated that something is acting weird concerning something in your question title. You should edit your post and ask a valid question to make this more understandable... most members wants to have to sift through that large chunk of code trying to put this into context.

Comment: I don't know how to put it anyway else the problem only occured on server side and that's the code what is causing the problem. The best way i could describe the problem is to show it directly

Comment: You should be able to construct a question. If you can't then you are just posting a "My code doesn't work, can someone fix it?". These types of questions do not belong on Stackoverflow as it is a Q & A site.

Comment: Ok next time i will remeber about the Q & A wesbite :) Tnks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

When you hide your content and load new content:

```
$('#content').hide('slow',loadContent);
```

You should make sure that as soon as it's hidden, the content is made empty:

```
                function loadContent() {
                    $('#content').empty();
                    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
                }
```

Comment: I think you would have to insert a delay in showNewContent(), unless you can find a way to know when the browser has loaded the data.

Comment: but delay in show new content woudn't fix it the problem. It's loading the content from old page